# How to keep full-screen windows on top when they don't have focus (Xubuntu 20.04)

Tags: xubuntu, multiple-monitors, fullscreen, focus

I have a multi-monitor setup. When I have a window on one-monitor full screen but move focus to a window on a different monitor (I have focus set to follow the mouse) the full screen window goes to the bottom of the stack of windows on that monitor, regardless of its position in the stack when it had focus, even if it set to be always on top, even if the other windows were not under the path of the mouse pointer to the other monitor. When focus moves back to the full-screen application the stack returns to how it was before focus was lost. This happens regardless of what application is full screen (firefox, chrome, feh, LibreOffice, gimp, Cities Skylines, vlc, etc)

Other than minimising all the other windows on the relevant monitor, is there a way to keep a fullscreen window on top when it doesn't have focus?